# Moved my Wordpress site and now it can't read the theme

Tags: permissions, debug

I moved my Wordpress website on Friday (so DNS propagation should be long finished) and now the site has no theme. I spent time yesterday re-installing the theme and Wordpress but to no avail. It won't recognize any theme, even Wordpress default

http://inspiringtravellers.com

Any ideas? I have deactivated all plug-ins and this didn't fix it. I believe it to be a permissions issue somewhere and others have also pointed to a .css file appearing missing though when I look at the ftp it is there. I spent ten hours on this yesterday trying everything and am starting fresh today.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Should also go on wordpress.SE

Answer (score 1):

I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" for a huge bunch of your CSS/JS, basically everything that's under the `wp-content` directory.

You might want to look into your file permissions - [here's what WP needs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress).

Comment: Would it help to just put the old wp-content folder from the old drive in its place since it looked perfect prior to the move?

Comment: It might help, depending on how you copy the files and whether their permissions are being somehow modified in the process. You could also be facing a `.htaccess` or general Apache conf issue, though. What are the current permissions on your wp-content folder?

Comment: It's 755... @vzwick

Answer (score 0):

did you made any change in database??like your previous site was http://inspiringtravellers.com/test/ and current site is http://inspiringtravellers.com. in that case you need to dump your database and search for http://inspiringtravellers.com/test and replace it with http://inspiringtravellers.com and then import it again.i hope this works.

Comment: I don't think so...my host did the move so I can't confirm that the database wasn't changed but I doubt they would change it.